# Find value in array with recursion

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

I am trying to find a value in an array with a specific method.

```
public void findElement(int valueToFind)
{
    FindElementInArray(valueToFind, 0, _array.Length - 1);
}

public void FindElementInArray(int value, int lb, int rb)
    {          
        int currIndex = (rb - lb) / 2;
        if (_array[currIndex] == value)
        {
            //Value found
            Console.WriteLine("Value found");
            return;
        }

        //If found value is smaller than searched value
        else if (_array[currIndex] < value)
        {
            FindElementInArray(value, currIndex+1, rb);
        }

        //If found value is bigger than searched value
        else
        {
            FindElementInArray(value, lb, currIndex - 1);
        }
```

So I search the middle of the array, if the value is bigger than the value we look for, we search the middle of the left half and so on...

But it doesnt find some values even if they are in the array. Can someone see a mistake?

Comment: FYI that's called a `Binary Search`.

Comment: Is your input array sorted? Because it has to be if binary search should work

Comment: Without actually looking at the code: have you made sure your array is sorted?

Comment: @PhilippSch & nvoigt: yes the array is sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the index wrong.

```
int currIndex = (rb - lb) / 2;
```

You need to get the middle point of rb and lb which would be:

```
int currIndex = lb + (rb - lb) / 2;
// or
// int currIndex = (lb + rb) / 2;
```

You will also need an exit out of the recursion somehow if the value isn't present because currently it will just go on and cause a stack overflow. You could do that by checking to ensure `lb` and `rb` are different for example:

```
if (_array[currIndex] == value)
{
    //Value found
    Console.WriteLine("Value found");
    return;
}
else if (lb != rb)
{
    //If found value is smaller than searched value
    else if (_array[currIndex] < value)
    {
        FindElementInArray(value, currIndex+1, rb);
    }

    //If found value is bigger than searched value
    else
    {
        FindElementInArray(value, lb, currIndex - 1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler Np, I updated the answer again, you need to exit the recursion somehow. Make sure you accept the answer by hitting the tick :)

Comment: lb + (rb - lb) /2 == (lb + rb) / 2

Answer (score 0):

```
int currIndex = (rb - lb) / 2;
```

should be

```
int currIndex = (rb + lb) / 2;
```

You need to find a midpoint.